# IIS7 shows welcome screen in Firefox, Internet Explorer works correctly

Tags: firefox, iis-7

Has anyone encountered the following problem: I have IIS7 running on my computer. On that same computer, I open IE7 and the website works (http://localhost/web.site/Default.aspx). Put that same url in Firefox 3 and I get the welcome screen of IIS7, a big image with IIS7 in the middle and 'Welcome' in several different languages. Clicking on the image leads you to http://www.iis.net/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One browser accesses your server via 127.0.0.1, and another via your external IP.

Make sure virtualhost works with all network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your browsers have different locals set , only guessing as I have not used IIS7

Answer (score 0):

Strange. That happened to me this morning (April 9, 2009), but the other way around. I was trying to get to Dell.ca. IE7 brought me to that IIS7 Welcome screen and Firefox brought me to the correct site. Happened 3 times before it corrected itself.

I do not have IIS anywhere on my network and my default home page is Google, which came up without a problem. The redirection occurred when I typed the new URL. I wonder if Dell is using IIS7...